# Add/remove state array item immutably

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've set up some buttons and can store in an array which one is clicked or not with a function (clickHandle). So I've set up a condition in className so that if the button is clicked or not it should change className. However this doesn't seem to work and I'm guessing because the className needs to be updated through a function.

Here's my code :

````
const [click, setClick] = useState([]);

  const clickHandle = (id) => {
    click.indexOf(id) === -1
      ? click.push(id)
      : click.splice(click.indexOf(id), 1);
    console.log(click);
  }; 

 return (
<div className="options-container">
              {data &&
                data.additionalCharges.map((data, index) => {
                  return (
                    <button
                      onClick={async () => clickHandle(data.id)}
                      className={
                        click.indexOf(data.id) === -1
                          ? "options-unclicked"
                          : "options-clicked"
                      }
                      key={data.id}
                    >
                      <div>{data.title}</div>
                      <div>{data.description}</div>
                      <div>
                        {data.price.amount} € {data.price.unit}
                      </div>
                    </button>
                  );
                })}
            </div> 
)```
````

Comment: you forgot to update the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Array.prototype.push()` and `Array.prototype.splice()`, both mutating your state in-place, which doesn't let React detect the changes you've made.

Instead, your state manipulation approach should be immutable. So, your click handler should look something, like:

```
const clickHandle = (id) => {
   click.includes(id)
     ?  setClick(click.filter(_id => _id !== id))
     :  setClick([...click, id]) 
}
```

Comment: Never used .includes . This works perfectly as well! And the code is DRY af! Thank you!

Comment: Just did! Sorry that was my first time asking a question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have not update the state in your onClick listener `clickHandle`

Should be something like,

```
const clickHandle = (id) => {
    let newData = [...click];
    newData.indexOf(id) === -1
      ? newData.push(id)
      : newData.splice(newData.indexOf(id), 1);
   setClick(newData);
  };
```

This way, your component will re-render on click and classname will be reflected.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved it instantly!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding and removing buttons using click variable instead you should use setClick so that your component you get re-rendered

replace your clickHandler with following

```
const clickHandle = (id) => {
    let buttons = [...click]
    buttons.indexOf(id) === -1
      ? buttons.push(id)
      : buttons.splice(buttons.indexOf(id), 1);
    console.log(buttons);
    setClick(buttons) // this will render your component
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much that solved it instantly!